# Cannot find sparkskins_xxx.swf

Tags: apache-flex, flex-spark

I am trying out to deploy a flex application in one of our servers. I was able to deploy it but running it causes some problems like missing swfs.

One of these missing swfs is the sparkskins, which I am not sure where to get from.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should change framework linkage to "Merged into code" for you project.

In FlashBuilder this option is here: Project Properties window -> Flex Build Path list item -> Library Path tab -> Framework linkage combobox.

After this your sdk swfs will be compiled into your flash app.

Comment: This is not exactly the right answer, but it did point me to the right direction. To be exact, it's the unchecking of 'Remove unused RSLs' that work :) (didn't try this suggestion though, because i had no control over what was deployed and i was just duct-tape fixing it by deploying individual files like missing swfs manually).

Comment: I'm glad my answer was useful!